# Angular cli stopped live recompiling when saving changes

Tags: macos, dns, localhost, angular-cli

I tried few solutions on my Mac for solving DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error, and since that my Angular projects are running, but when I save changes, it is not auto recompiling(looks like the watch is not responding).
The steps that I did before it started were:
- renew DHCP lease in the TCP/IP of network settings tab.
- adding DNS server address.
- running this command in the terminal: `dscacheutil -flushcache`.

EDIT - When I run `ng serve --watch` the recompiling works, but without the `--watch` it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
after running once the `ng serve -- watch` running only the `ng-serve` started to work again!

Hope I manage to help someone with this issue and solution...